# Express next() error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working with node+express+MongoDB.

I dont understand this error. 
When I comment next() it's fine and works but when I use next() I'm getting the error:

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**

```
videos.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        Video.find({},function (err,videosCollection) {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }

            if(!videosCollection.length)
            {
                console.log("Videos not found");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("videos found");
                res.status(200).json(videosCollection);
            }
        })
      //  next();
    })
```

Comment: There is nothing to go 'next' to.   You have effectively ended the res when you send the status/json.   'Next' is only needed for middleware when you need to pass it on to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` in express passes async control to the next middlewear in the chain.

This is how `next` should be used. To pass errors down the chain of middleware.

```
videos.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        Video.find({},function (err,videosCollection) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                // pass the error along
                next(err);
            }else if(!videosCollection.length){
                // pass a new error along
                next(new Error("Videos noz found"));
            }else{
                console.log("videos found");
                // no need to call next
                // res.json finishes the connection
                res.status(200).json(videosCollection);
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use res.status or res.send the request has ended and the function does a soft return. When you do next() you're passing it along in the chain of middleware and endpoints. So basicly, you'll do double return.

So the message tells you that you cant return a response after the response has been returned to the client.

Only when you're writing middleware do you need to use next.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the next function it will call the following middleware *after* this route.

You are calling this function *before* the callback is called in Video.find.  If you want to call next, you have to do it inside the callback as below.

```
  videos.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    Video.find({},function (err,videosCollection) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if(!videosCollection.length)
        {
            console.log("Videos not found");

        }
        else
        {
            console.log("videos found");
            res.status(200).json(videosCollection);

        }
        next()
    })
})
```

Comment: this won't work and will throw an error when `res.json` and `next` are called in the same request.

Comment: @PhilPoore next and res.json are separate concepts.  All next does is move to the second middleware, res.json doesn't interfere with this.  I tested this code out and it works fine.  Sends the response then runs the second middleware.  As other answers explain, next gives responsibility to the next middleware

Comment: have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/philpoore/6de35cb84ae353270f00c9d80d655751 you can't, and shouldn't pass control to next middleware once you have already called res.json.
you could put a `return ;` inside the else to stop it falling through, but then it gets messy code and really needs reworking.

Comment: For example, on error or 0 videos the connection will console.log the error, but doesn't pass this along to next middleware as per express convention.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree, not the best way to do it at all but didn't want to make too many assumptions about the rest of the code in there.  I would normally not use next in a route at all.  His use case and legacy code may require it, hard to tell.